# The Garmin Connect IQ SDK on Fedora

Tags: garmin, connectiq

I need to install Garmin Connect SDK and Eclipse and create project for Garmin products. I am following

http://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/getting-started/

I am doing this in Fedora and since, Connect IQ SDK is available for only Windows and Mac, I am following this [site](http://blog.aaronboman.com/programming/connectiq/2014/11/13/the-garmin-connect-iq-sdk-on-ubuntu-linux/) to install it in Fedora. As per  orx57 comment in that website, I executed dos2unix ~/connectiq/bin/monkey{c,do} before the second step "chmod +x monkeyc monkeydo" but after this, if I type monkeyc in the console, it says "Command Not Found". Its the same if I execute the final step after doing all the steps above. Can someone help me on is this resolvable or what can I do to get the installation working?

Answer (score 5):

You can also check out my Connect IQ seed project that contains script to run and package your project - you don't need to have Eclipse or the plugin - just the SDK and it works on linux, too.
https://github.com/danielsiwiec/garmin-connect-seed

Answer (score 0):

"Command Not Found" - this means that the file is not found. Try execute export PATH=$PATH:~/connectiq/bin

Or if you have edited .bashrc, then you must restart the console (logout-login)